# reversing an iterator that depends on end()

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

Let's assume that I want to write a bidirectional iterator that iterates over all non-zero values of any container providing `begin()`/`end()`/`rbegin()`/`rend()`. I would have to rewrite `operator++()` to skip over all zeros it encounters. To make sure it is still valid, it would have to check against `end()` and `rend()` of the container each time. Something in the lines of the following:

```cpp
template<class Container, class Iter> 
struct NonZeroIter: public Iter
{
  Container& c;

  using Parent = Iter;
  using Parent::Parent;
  using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;

  bool is_valid() const { return *(*this) != 0; }
  bool is_end()   const { return *this == c.end(); }
  bool is_rend()  const { return *this == c.rend(); }

  NonZeroIter(Container& _c, const Iter& _it):
    Parent(_it),
    c(_c)
  { if(!is_end() && !is_valid()) ++(*this); }

  NonZeroIter& operator++()
  {
    if(!is_end()){
      do{
        Parent::operator++();
      } while(!is_end() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator--()
  {
    if(!is_rend()){
      do{
        Parent::operator--();
      } while(!is_rend() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator++(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp; }
  NonZeroIter& operator--(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); --(*this); return tmp; }

};
```

Now, I want to make a reverse-iterator of `NonZeroIter` using `std::reverse_iterator` but to do this I would have to check against `rend()` whenever `NonZeroIter` checks against `end()` and vice versa. Is there a nice way (avoiding overhead if possible) of doing this or do I have to write my own corresponding reverse-iterator class?

Comment: I think you are taking it on from the wrong end. Make an iterator adaptor that skips zeros without assuming anything about the base iterator type. Then to reverse the thing, don't "make a `reverse_iterator` from `NonZeroIter`", but "make a `NonZeroIter` from a `reverse_iterator`".

Comment: but to skip zeros, you need to check against either ```end()``` or ```rend()``` depending on the base iterator type (if I am not mistaken). So there can be no iterator skipping zeros that does not assume anything about the base itertor type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of @vll I ended up with the following code:

```cpp
// these structs compile-time translate begin,end to rbegin,rend for reverse iters
template<class Container, class Iter>
struct BeginEndIters
{
  using iterator     = Iter;
  static iterator begin(Container& c) { return c.begin(); }
  static iterator end(Container& c) { return c.end(); }
};
template<class Container, class Iter>
struct BeginEndIters<Container, std::reverse_iterator<Iter>>
{
  using iterator     = std::reverse_iterator<Iter>;
  static iterator begin(Container& c) { return c.rbegin(); }
  static iterator end(Container& c) { return c.rend(); }
};

template<class Container, class Iter>
struct NonZeroIter: public Iter
{
  Container& c;

  // this is the main change
  using BeginEnd = BeginEndIters<Container, Iter>;
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^

  using Parent = Iter;
  using Parent::Parent;
  using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;

  bool is_valid() const { return *(*this) != 0; }
  bool is_end()   const { return *this == BeginEnd::end(c); }
  bool is_past_begin()  const { return *this == std::prev(BeginEnd::begin(c)); }

  NonZeroIter(Container& _c, const Iter& _it):
    Parent(_it),
    c(_c)
  { if(!is_end() && !is_valid()) ++(*this); }

  NonZeroIter& operator++()
  {
    if(!is_end()){
      do{
        Parent::operator++();
      } while(!is_end() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator--()
  { 
    if(!is_past_begin()){
      do{
        Parent::operator--();
      } while(!is_past_begin() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator++(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp; }
  NonZeroIter& operator--(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); --(*this); return tmp; }  
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `NonZeroIter` checking explicitly against `end()` and `rend()`, the constructor should check the iteration direction and choose the beginning (`begin()` or `rbegin()`) and end (`end()` or `rend()`). These can be saved as local variables and checked against.

Instead of checking against "rend" in `operator--()`, you can check against "begin" (index represented by `begin()` is same as `rend() - 1`).

All iterators of standard containers are based on `std::reverse_iterator`, so you can use that knowledge to find the direction of `_it`.

Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_reverse_iterator : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_reverse_iterator<std::reverse_iterator<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class Container, class Iter> 
struct NonZeroIter: public Iter
{
  using Parent = Iter;
  using Parent::Parent;
  using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
private:      
  Parent begin, end;

  bool is_valid() const { return *(*this) != 0; }
  bool is_end()   const { return *this == end; }
  bool is_begin()  const { return *this == begin; }

public:
  NonZeroIter(Container& c, const Iter& _it):
    Parent(_it),
    begin(is_reverse_iterator<Parent> ? c.rbegin() : c.begin()),
    end(is_reverse_iterator<Parent> ? c.rend() : c.end()),
  { if (!is_end() && !is_valid()) ++(*this); }

  NonZeroIter& operator++()
  {
    if (!is_end()){
      do{
        Parent::operator++();
      } while(!is_end() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator--()
  {
    // Smallest possible value is begin, but you could also make that begin - 1
    if (!is_begin()){
      do{
        Parent::operator--();
      } while(!is_begin() && !is_valid());
    }
    return *this;
  }

  NonZeroIter& operator++(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp; }
  NonZeroIter& operator--(int) { NonZeroIter tmp(*this); --(*this); return tmp; }

};
```

Comment: While this is a nice solution, I would consider storing two more iterators a considerable overhead. Could this overhead be pushed into compile-time by templating the ```NonZeroIter``` with a ```begin()``` and ```end()``` function?

Comment: also, this will give ```error: operands to ?: have different types``` if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to have a base iterator class, where `is_end` and `is_rend` are virtual abstract functions.

Then create the forward and reverse iterator classes inheriting from the base class, and implementing the `is_end` and `is_rend` functions as needed by each iterator type.

Comment: Doesn't that incur VTable lookups (which I would consider overhead to be avoided)? But maybe there is a template-based solution along those lines (see comment to the other solution)

Comment: @igel Maybe, but the compiler might be able to optimize it away, or it might not add as much overhead as one might believe. Build with optimization enabled and profile and benchmark. If it turns out to be one of the top two or three bottlenecks in the program, then use some other solution.